# ALL car keys have stopped working

Tags: key, lexus, keyless-entry, immobilizer

I have a 10 year old Lexus RX400 which was working perfectly yesterday however today I can't unlock it.  I've tried all 3 keys and none of them will work.  The red light on the key flashes when I press unlock so the battery can't be dead (and to die on all 3 on the same day would be very coincidental!).  I can open the car door manually but then the immobiliser kicks in and the car will not start.  Any help?

Comment: I take it the car battery isn’t dead? If the immobilizer is kicking in try turning the key in the passenger door 3 times if it doesn’t have a passenger keyhole do it in the drivers door.

Answer (score 0):

Your Receiver door control which receives signal from your remote keys is not functionning. Below is the location of the receiver:
[image]

I would do the following:

1. Disconnect and reconnect to check the if keys are working
2. Reprogram the keys to see if they are working again (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmCN-YDkqwo&vl=en)
3. Replace the unit if this is not the case

Comment: 1 - disconnect and reconnect what? The receiver, the vehicle battery? the remote?

Comment: The door receiver control